# Haskell IO russian symbols

Tags: haskell, character-encoding, cyrillic

I an trying to process a file which contains russian symbols. When reading and after writing some text to the file I get something like:

`\160\192\231\229\240\225\224\233\228\230\224\237`

How can I get normal symbols?

Comment: i try parse web page www.trade.su/search?ext=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got success.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ImplicitParams #-}

import Network.HTTP
import Text.HTML.TagSoup
import Data.Encoding
import Data.Encoding.CP1251
import Data.Encoding.UTF8

openURL x =  do 
        x <- simpleHTTP (getRequest x)
        fmap (decodeString CP1251) (getResponseBody x)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    tags <- fmap parseTags $ openURL "http://www.trade.su/search?ext=1"
    let TagText r  = partitions (~== "<input type=checkbox>") tags !! 1 !! 4
    appendFile "out" r
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are getting strings with backslashes and numbers in, then it sounds like you might be calling "print" when you want to call "putStr".

Answer (score 2):

If you deal with Unicode, you might try [utf8-string package](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/utf8-string)

```
import System.IO hiding (hPutStr, hPutStrLn, hGetLine, hGetContents, putStrLn)
import System.IO.UTF8
import Codec.Binary.UTF8.String (utf8Encode)
main = System.IO.UTF8.putStrLn "Вася Пупкин"
```

However it didn't work well in my windows CLI garbling the output because of codepage. I expect it to work fine on other Unix-like systems if your locale is set correctly. However writing to file should be successfull on all systems.

UPDATE:

[An example](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/decl/2731107.flat.aspx) on encoding package usage.

Comment: He's not dealing with unicode. According to firefox the page he linked is encoded in Windows-1251.

Comment: Then [encoding package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/encoding) may be useful, it has [System.Encoding.CP1251](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/encoding/0.6.3/doc/html/Data-Encoding-CP1251.html).

Comment: I have some problems to install this package on windows. Can not find library 

i try like this:
cd c:\Users\test_8\Desktop\encoding-0.6.3

runhaskell Setup.hs configure --extra-include-dirs="c:\Users\test_8\Desktop\encoding-0.6.3" --extra-lib-dirs="c:\Users\test_8\Desktop\encoding-0.6.3"

but get this:
Setup.hs: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing header file: system_encoding.h

Comment: required  localinfo.h. I can not find it.

Comment: @Anton: Please, paste your sources somewhere, for example [here](http://freebsd.pastebin.com/) if they aren't so huge.

Comment: import Text.HTML.TagSoup
import Text.HTML.Download


main :: IO ()
main = do
    tags <- fmap parseTags $ openURL "http://www.trade.su/search?ext=1"
    let r =  partitions (~== "<input type=checkbox>") tags !! 1
    appendFile "out" (show r)

Comment: This is does not work:

{-# LANGUAGE ImplicitParams #-}
import Text.HTML.TagSoup
import Text.HTML.Download
import Prelude hiding (appendFile)
import System.IO.Encoding
import Data.Encoding.CP1251



main :: IO ()
main = do
    tags <- fmap parseTags $ openURL "http://www.trade.su/search?ext=1"
    let r  = partitions (~== "<input type=checkbox>") tags !! 1
    let ?enc = CP1251 
    appendFile "out" (show r)

Comment: I've just given up installing encoding package on Windows, haven't GHC for Unix on hand. This is interesting how you managed to install it.

Comment: I Could not install  on Windows too.

Comment: @Anton: Mate, I can no longer help you, since I don't have GHC for *nix, sorry. I wish google will help you. And it would be nice if you answered yourself here. ;)

Comment: Thanks. 
I can not understand reason of my problem. Hence i do not know what i need find in Google.

Comment: @Anton: Also make sure that `appendFile` you use is imported from `System.IO.Encoding` rather `System.IO`. Try to use `System.IO.Encoding.appendFile` call.